# What's the best way to control a Matrix of 10 x 20 LED with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: led, arduino, java

I developed a Tetris-Clone in Java. I want to run it on the Raspberry Pi and display it on a 10 x 20 Home-made-LED-Matrix. My question is: What is the best way to achieve that. Here are the solutions I thought about thus far:

1. Build a matrix and use multiplexing. Pro: Great performance! Little effort in the workshop :-) Cons: That's not gonna work with a standard Raspberry Pi, because it would require 30 GPIO pins. Even the A+ offers only 26.
2. Build an array of 25 shift registers (for better performance make 5 groups of 5 shift registers each) and serially shift in the required bits. Pros: Well, it works! Cons: It's a lot of stuff to solder and the runtime performance is bad!
3. Use a Arduino Mega to control a matrix as described in (1) and control that from the Arduino running the Tetris logic. Pro: Works! Offers better performance than (2). Cons: Big overhead! Worse performance than (1).

What is your opinion? How would you tackle the problem I described? I do not want to use a prebuilt LED-Matrix by the way!

Comment: You could also use [I²C I/O expanders](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/interface/i2c-io-expander-products.page). There are several models with 16 inputs/outputs. PIs all have at least one I²C port. Also, the [PI2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/) has 40 GPIO, which would suit your needs.

Comment: Doesn't the Pi2 only offer 26 of its 40 pins as GPIO?

Comment: No, it offers more. The 26 pins in questions is about compatibility. While the 40 pins header has more GPIO than the A model, the first 26 pins are compatible between the two. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-a-plus/ .

Comment: Here it states that of these 40 pins, only 29 can be used to control LEDs etc. http://pi4j.com/pins/model-a-plus.html

Comment: Ok, my bad, sorry. Looks like you're 4 pins short and an I/O port expander is the most straightforward way. Note however that the GPIOs assigned to the flat connectors (display & camera) should also be usable. I have to get my hands back on the magazine where I read that though.

Comment: Adafruit has a good writeup of using addressable LEDs with the Pi: https://learn.adafruit.com/light-painting-with-raspberry-pi/overview . This uses a grand total of 2 GPIO pins. The tutorial is based on LPD8806 LED strips, but it appears that it may be possible to adapt the code used for WS2801 LEDs as well: http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&p=162366 . I've done quite a lot of Arduino projects with WS2801s and found them pretty neat things to work with.